# Why does Google webmaster render cause error: Intl is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-search-console, google-crawlers, intl

When I use Google's Webmaster tools and try to "Fetch as Google" to certain pages of my site, the site that is rendered by Google is missing a lot of data (It looks like a javascript error happens)

I have an error logging system on my website that saves errors to a database for me to view them. The error that Google is causing is "ReferenceError: Intl is not defined"

My question is: How do I render my page like Google is, in order to throw the error locally so I can find it? Or, is there a solution to the error that Google is throwing?

Things I've Tried:

1. Disabling localstorage (Random I know)
2. Adding:

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
   ```

PS: I do not use Intl directly in my web app, some of my node packages contain it (making it difficult to track down).

PPS: My site is an Angular 2 application: however Google renders many of the pages fine.

Comment: You have to add &unknown=polyfill to polifill.io url so it sends stuff to googlebot.